# Ionic, cell phone keyboard scrolls buttons

Tags: ionic3

I have a problem when I run my Ionic 3 application on an Android phone. It is a login page with some buttons at the bottom of the screen and **when you click on an ion-input type text, the cell phone keyboard appears and moves my buttons upwards, placing them on the ion-input**. **I would like to know how to do so that this does not happen, that the buttons are always fixed according to my design** and the keyboard floats on them, thank you very much

Comment: code ? It may be a css issue